# Does the Law of Large Number have a convergent rate?

Tags: probability

As we all know, many algorithms have the convergent rates such as a exponentially or polynomially convergent rate. In the stochastic sense, I know the law of large number states that for a large number of independent and identically distributed (IID) variables, the average of their summation approaches to the expected value of the random variable. My question is whether the Law of Large Number has a convergent rate?

Comment: [Rate of convergence in the Law of Large Numbers](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/203044/rate-of-convergence-in-the-law-of-large-numbers)